# This should work : open() in python

Tags: python, file-io

I am attempting to open and write to a file at the end of some for loop I have. However,
I get a "output" undefined prompt. (See code below)

Am I not declaring what output is as the same time I open my file 'output.txt' in write mode?

```
for X in Y
    ....
    output = open(output.txt, 'w')
    output.writelines(lines)
    output.close()
```

This should be working right? is my syntax wrong? Or must I declare output = open outside of the for loop?

Notes: Python 2.7.3

Answered:  Thank you all, I was trying to open output.txt not 'output.txt' hence python couldn't understand my declaration.

Comment: What is the actual error and traceback?

Comment: You probably want to use a context manager for the file (see `with`) and move the opening/closing of the file outside of the loop unless there is a good reason for keeping it inside.  Not the issue, but generally considered better programming style.

Comment: I actually am converting to the `with` syntax now, I will move the open outside of the loop too. Since I am using `with` there is no need for a close statement correct?  or would it just read better having a close at the end of the whole loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filename `output.txt` is a string, but you have not quoted it.  So the undefined `output` Python complains about is not the variable result of the `open()` call, but rather the improperly quoted string inside the `open()` call.

It gets misinterpreted as some object called `open` on which you are accessing a property `txt`.

```
output = open('output.txt', 'w')
```

Comment: Ahh! Your so right, thank you for point out the newbie mistake. :)

Answer (score 1):

`output.txt` is not quoted; so it's not seen as a string literal but rather as variable by python.

It should be:

```
output = open("output.txt", 'w')
```

---

**Moreover**, it's better to use the `with` structure if you are using `python >= 2.5`:

```
with open("output.txt", 'w') as output:
    output.writelines(lines)
```

because it will handle file closure for you automatically to avoid leaking resources, no matter what happens.

Comment: Thank sampson, I have see the `with` before and now understand it.

Answer (score 0):

`output = open(output.txt, 'w')`

I think the error is because output.txt isn't a string. Try

`output = open('output.txt', 'w')`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put "output.txt" in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Errors aside, it may not be doing exactly what you intend. Opening a file in write mode and writing to it will completely replace that file. If you wish to append something in a loop to that file, you'd want to open it in append mode:

```
output = open("output.txt", "a")
for x in y:
    output.writelines(x) #or whatever you're writing
output.close()
```